# Firing a lot of PropertyChangedEvents during one button click handler

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have the following problem in an uwp app.

There is a listview which is bind to an observable collection. There is also  a button which can change one property in each of the items in the collection which results in lots of PropertyChanged events being fired. This works well when there are not more then around 25 items in the collection. If there are more, i get the following exception.

```
{"Layout cycle detected.  Layout could not complete."}
```

I think this is because there are to many PropertyChanged events which results in to many UI updates during one button click. I tried to update the property without firing a PropertyChanged event but i can't get the UI to update then.

Comment: You will need to fire the PropertyChanged event at some point in order to update the UI. Consider switching from the `ObservableCollection` to a `List` and then fire the PopertyChanged manually just once.

Comment: Can you please post your code? We can't debug by guessing.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the suggestions. I was able to solve the problem now. When i change a property in the collection, another listview becomes visibles, which is also bound to a collection. So I guessed the ui just needs some time to display the inner list view and to calculate the new size of the outer listview. Here is what I did:

```
    Timer collapseTimer;

    internal void collapseAll()
    {
        collapseTimer = new Timer(collapseCallBack, null, 0, Timeout.Infinite);
    }


    private async void collapseCallBack(object state)
    {
        foreach (var item in views)
        {
           var asyncAction =  CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Low, () =>
         {
             item.IsCollapsed = true;
         });
            await Task.Delay(10);
        }
        collapseTimer.Dispose();
    }
```

When collapsAll() is called, a background thread starts which let's the ui change the property of each element one by one whenever it has time to do this.